# Splitting up File Input and Formatting Output in Java (Homewor)

Tags: java, string, file-io, java.util.scanner, token

So my class's lab assingment is to read in a text file with a city's name and some temperatures on one line (with any amount of lines) ex:

Montgomery 15 9.5 17

and print the name and the average of the temperatures. When printing out the name has to be to the left on the line, and the average should be printed with two digits after the decimal point, to the right on the line. I can assume no name is 30+ characters, and that the average can be printed in a field 10 characters wide (including the decimal point).

Here's what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class readFile2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader a = new FileReader("places.txt");

        StreamTokenizer b = new StreamTokenizer(a);

        ArrayList<Double> c = new ArrayList<Double>();

        /*System.out.println(
            String.format("%-10s:%10s", "ABCD", "ZYXW")); 
         **I found this to format an output. */

        double count = 0;

        while(b.nextToken() != b.TT_EOF);
        {
            if(b.ttype == b.TT_WORD)
        {
            System.out.print(b.sval);
        }
            if(b.ttype == b.TT_NUMBER)
            {
                c.add(b.nval);
                count ++;
            }

            double totaltemp = 0;                   // I need to figure out how to put
                                                    // this inside of an if statement
            for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)       // that can tell when it reaches
            {                                       // the last number/the end of the line
                totaltemp = c.get(i) + totaltemp;   //
                count++;                            //
            }                                       //
                                                    //
            System.out.print(totaltemp/count);      //
        }
    }
}
```

The second part is to modify the program so that the name of a cty may consist of more than one word (e.g., `New York')

I really appreciate any and all help and advice :)

Comment: Are all names just one word?

Comment: Yes. But for the second part the names may be two words

Comment: Is it always an MS Word (docx) file or just a plain text?

Comment: At first it was docx but now it's just plain text (places.txt) and I've updated the code to reflect that. I'll update it up there as well

Comment: In that case, I would imagine you would read in the text file line by line (LOTS of examples of this out there). Then I would use `String#split` with using a space as a delimiter (lots of examples on this too). Iterate through the new array knowing that (1) the first element will always be a word (should still do error checking) (2) The 2nd element may or may not be a word and (3) the rest are the numbers you're looking for.